# Correctly mapping a oneToOne relation in hibernate using JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, one-to-one

I have the following two tables

Table 1: Service:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy="service")
Routes routes;
```

Table 2: Routes:

```
@OneToOne(cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="service_id")
    Service service;

    @Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)
    Long service_id;

    public Long getService_id() {
        return this.service_id;
    }

    public void setService_id() {
        this.service_id = service_id;
    }
```

I have annotated both entities as tables. I have verified that the mappedBy entity is exactly the name of the table . But I keep getting the error

```
 @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on Service.routes references an unknown entity Routes
```

Comment: Routes is not annotated with javax.persistence.Entity, or is not in your persistence.xml.

Comment: That is not a `OneToOne` relation. "mappedBy" should be the FIELD on the other side of the relation when it is a BIDIRECTIONAL relation. Any `@Table` is totally optional to define the table name and nothing else. All of this is in any basic JPA tutorial. http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_1/jpa/mapping.html#one_one_relations

Comment: Thanks I've changed it.. The problem was that I didnt add the class to the dropwizard application class, but thanks for the info